# broadcom 43142 on archlinux: no interface

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, broadcom

It seems to be that the drivers are installed for BCM43142 on my laptop:

```
lspci -k
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0
        Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
        kernel modules: bcma
```

However, there seems to be no wireless interface associated with this device:

```
ip link
```

doesn't output any information for a wireless device. I've looked at the Archlinux docs and it doesn't say how to attach an interface (i.e. wlan0) to the wireless device. Any idea how I would go about correcting this issue?

```
dmesg| grep bcma
```

[image]

**Update** : I am getting the following `dmesg` output

```
[   11.069453] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[   11.561403] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[   12.718246] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: link up
[   12.718274] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp1s0: link becomes ready
[   15.017434] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[   38.022260] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[   71.026835] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[  114.025121] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[  148.297435] ERROR @wl_dev_intvar_get : error (-1)
[  148.297440] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_tx_power : error (-1)
[  167.028256] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[  230.049349] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[  293.054357] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[  356.117637] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[  356.125132] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[  419.109201] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[  482.052441] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[  545.067170] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[  550.596770] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[  608.087644] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[  671.100683] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[  671.108110] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[  674.041554] ERROR @wl_dev_intvar_get : error (-1)
[  674.041564] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_tx_power : error (-1)
[  734.132416] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[  797.080622] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[  860.126435] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[  923.084072] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[  986.177109] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[  986.184353] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[ 1011.528205] ERROR @wl_dev_intvar_get : error (-1)
[ 1011.528216] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_tx_power : error (-1)
[ 1049.095516] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[ 1112.124821] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[ 1175.102042] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[ 1238.133483] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[ 1301.125476] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[ 1364.117876] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[ 1427.121597] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[ 1490.152334] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[ 1553.171802] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
```

**Update2:**

`lspci -k`

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

`sudo iwlist scan`

```
wlp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning : Invalid argument
```

`ifconfig`

```
wlp2s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 76:24:fe:f7:5e:ce  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 17
```

Comment: Does `iwconfig` show anything useful?

Comment: It just shows: `enp1s0: no wireless extensions   lo:  no wireless extensions`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the [broadcom-wl-dkms](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/broadcom-wl-dkms/) package.

You can Install it from AUR  using `yaourt` (deprecated use `yay` instead) [please see the complete list on AUR helpers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR_helpers):

```
yaourt -S  broadcom-wl-dkms
```

Unload conflicting modules.

```
rmmod b43
rmmod ssb
rmmod bcma
```

Load the `wl` module:

```
modprobe -r wl
modprobe wl
```

Comment: So I ran into another problem. I did research a lot before I canme back here, but still no go. I am getting the following `dmesg` output posted in the original question.

Comment: After upgrading kernel re-install the driver , if dosn't work run `depmod -a` and blacklist conflicting driver in `/etc/modprobe.d/modprobe.conf`